# Problem involving direct sum of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:U \longrightarrow U$ be a linear transformation, with $T^2(x) = T(x)$. how can i show that
$$U = N(T) \bigoplus T(U)?$$
I spent a lot of time thinking about this problem and I couldn't solve it... :(

Comment: What have you tried? Did you prove that $N(T) \cap T(U) = \{0 \}$?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take $x\in U$ let $$y=x-Tx$$ then $y\in N(T)$ because
$$Ty=Tx-TTx=Tx-Tx=0$$ so

$$x=(x-Tx)+Tx$$ This shows that every element is a sum of an element in the kernel and an element of the image. Need only now show that $N(T)\cap T(U)=0$ and this is easy.

Comment: Please do not answer questions without context. You can read this: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1